# How to retrieve data using where clause from 2 different tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I have two tables `[basic]` & `[info]` both have a primary key `email_id`. Now I want to retrieve info from the `basic` table but the `where` clause should have searching condition from both the tables

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    basic.f_name, 
    basic.l_name 
FROM 
    basic 
CROSS JOIN 
    info 
WHERE 
    (basic.email_id = basic.email_id) 
    AND (basic.caste LIKE '%' + @caste + '%') 
    AND (info.diet =  @diet )
```

(this query is written in asp for gridview but its not working)

Comment: You've got basic.email_id = basic.email_id where you probably mean basic.email_id = info.email_id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT basic.f_name, basic.l_name 
FROM basic INNER JOIN info ON basic.email_id = info.email_id 
WHERE (basic.caste LIKE '%' + @caste + '%') AND (info.diet = @diet )
```

Comment: Side note - It's not a universal preference but more often than not people like to use INNER JOIN ... ON for the joining parts and WHERE for the data-specific filtering parts.  And people usually just use a comma for CROSS JOIN if they don't like INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

When you do an inner join you are actually using a cross join with a where clause. In an inner join all the data is combined (cartesian product) and then filtered through with a where clause. Therefore, I think your code would be cleaner using an inner join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT basic.f_name, basic.l_name 
FROM basic 
CROSS JOIN info 
WHERE (basic.email_id = basic.email_id)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT basic.f_name, basic.l_name 
FROM basic INNER JOIN info ON basic.email_id = info.email_id
```

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the 'equivalence', but the second query is a lot more plausible than the first.  CROSS JOIN is very seldom part of the answer.  That's not a blanket denial; there are occasions when CROSS JOIN is exactly what is needed.  Those occasions are few and far between, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    basic.f_name, 
    basic.l_name 
FROM 
    basic as basic
INNER JOIN 
    info as info 
    ON basic.email_id = info.email_id
WHERE 
    (basic.caste LIKE '%' + @caste + '%') 
    AND (info.diet =  @diet )
```